# Unity AndroidJavaObject not working without showing errors

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine, ubuntu

I have been trying to call a Java method in unity. Not working for me, even the simplest example from the docs

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        AndroidJavaObject jo = new AndroidJavaObject ("java.lang.String", "some string");
        int hash = jo.Call<int> ("hashCode");
        Debug.Log ("hash=" + hash);
    }
}
```

Unity console prints `hash=0`, which is not the hash code for provided String. Even if I change and use `java.lang.StringInvalidClass` as class name, unity still reports same result to the console without notifying errors. I can even try to call toString, toStringa, toInvalid2 and they always return empty string without showing errors.

This is a brand new 2d project with only script displayed above, attached to camara object. I am using Ubuntu, Unity 2019.4 and project platform is Android.

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: "fails without errors", either it has errors, or it doesn't fail. Maybe it doesn't do what you expect it to do, but that doesn't mean it fails. It's more likely an issue with the code. You might want to check this: https://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-calculate-md5-and-sha-hash-values-in-java

Comment: As far as I can see from unity documentation both `AndroidJavaObject` class and `Call` method expect 2nd parameter to be an `array`. Not sure if string qualifies in that situation as character array.

Comment: Hi @stultuske. As mentioned, even if I use java.lang.StringInvalidClass, unity prints the same. Of course StringInvalidClass does not exists and it should throw an error. So, something is failing without actually throwing or displaying an error in the console. I used a simple example to avoid complexity.

Comment: Hi @user3647971. Yes, AndroidJavaObject and Call works using an array as second parameter, but if no parameter required or it just requires one, it is acceptable to not provide it and provide just one.
In fact, the code provided is directly copied from uninty docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/es/530/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.Call.html

Comment: @Jhovanni I noticed that documentation is for older version of unity. [See here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.html) It should be included in `UnityEngine.AndroidJNIModule`. Probably not the issue, but worth checking out.

Comment: Thank you @user3647971. You are right. I went to 2019.4 documentation, however it have the same information at the end. I mean, module changes but it is still part of unity default packages. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself after some time working with unity.

All examples in the web and unity documentation doesn't mention it, which is weird since it is something simple to mention and about confusions: code needs to run as an android application. Editor or even unity remote does not work, **in order to use AndroidJavaObject and related classes, your code needs to run as an android application installed in the phone**.